# Computing distance to clique in FPT time

Tags: np-hard, parameterized-complexity

I am a research scholar, and I currently work in parameterized algorithms. My current work involves proving that a problem is FPT for the parameter *distance to clique*. Although it is known that computing a *distance to clique* of size $k$ can be done in FPT time using a simple branching algorithm, I couldn't figure out how. Please elaborate on this. Once I get this, then I can assume that the *distance to clique* is given and solve the rest. 
For a graph $G = (V, E)$, the parameter *distance to clique* is the cardinality of the smallest set $D \subseteq V$ such that $V \setminus D$ is a clique.

Comment: If the distance to clique is 0, then its about solving the problem for a clique. If i assume that for distance to clique it is FPT, then in this case it is polynomial time solvable on clique. @PålGD

Answer (score 1):

The distance to clique is the fewest number of vertices to remove such that the resulting graph is a clique.

Let us take the complement graph $\overline G$ of $G$.  Now, we instead want to find the fewest number of vertices to remove such that the resulting graph is *edgeless*.

Recall that if $I$ is edgeless (i.e. an independent set), then $C$ is a *vertex cover* of $G$.  Hence, distance to clique is simply vertex cover in the complement graph.